# XSLT output child elements with different namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I did search in google before posting but i could not find a answer so,I want to post the solution here so it could be helpful for other developers.

**Scenario:**
sample Input

```
    <CarYard>
       <Cars>
          <A>honda</A>
          <B>BMW</B>
          <C>AUDI</C>
      </Cars>
   </CarYard>$
```

How to generate a namespace for elements A, B,C
When you are doing dynamic template match.

Answer (score 0):

```
           <xsl:template match="CarYard">       
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//CarYard/*[1]" mode="addNamespace"/>
        </xsl:element>          
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="addNamespaceToAllChild">
    <xsl:variable name="ELEM_NAME" select="concat('ns1:',local-name())"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$ELEM_NAME}" xmlns:ns1="http://test.namespace/generic">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="addNamespace">
    <xsl:variable name="ELEM_NAME" select="concat('ns1:',local-name())"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$ELEM_NAME}" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.test.namespace/generic">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="addNamespaceToAllChild"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Now the resulted out put will be

```
<CarYard>
   <ns1:Cars>
      <ns1:A>honda</ns1:A>
      <ns1:B>BMW</ns1:B>
      <ns1:C>AUDI</ns1:C>
  </ns1:Cars>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be going out of its way to put the children of CarYard in one namespace (http://test.namespace/generic), the grandchildren in another (http://schemas.test.namespace/generic), and the great-grandchildren (if there are any) somewhere else. But this isn't reflected in either your requirements or in the sample output you show.

Comment: The other thing I would add is that it's a little sad that you should be trying to solve this problem by searchiing on google. Google can be quite good for some programming problems, for example tracking down the meaning of a particular error message, but it's not really the way to learn techniques in a new programming language. Get yourself a couple of good books, and read them!

Answer (score 0):

A valid example of outputting a namespaced element would be like this.

```
    <xsl:element name="x:include" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@href"/>
    </xsl:element>
```

Which would produce something like this.

```
<x:include xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="../topics/topic.dita">
```